# Localstorage modify state?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

i'm new to vuejs, I hope you are well? I have a quick question about token storage and user information (name, etc.....). For the moment I use the following configuration. The user enters his information and logs in, this triggers an action in the login store that retrieves the token and user information, once retrieved it triggers mutations that change the states of the variables and records the data in local storage. . I have seen configurations where people directly assign local storage in the variables of the example states:

```
state: {
   token: localStorage.getItem('token'),"
}
```

Logically, it is the mutations that can modify the states and technically here it is localstorage. Is this good even so at the level of conventions?

[Here is a diagram of how I proceed, is this the right solution?.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9p7o.png)

Thank you in advance

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Is my way of proceeding as shown in the diagram good? Or should I assign the states to the local storage directly? since it will change the state at reload when we are supposed to go through mutations not? or this way is appropriate?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://flaviocopes.com/vuex-persist-localstorage/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I finally got the same information on another forum but for a "more up-to-date" library "https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate". One offered me another option: to store user data in a js-cookie